# Manipulation of array (generate table)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the follow arrays:

Array `$eventos`:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [Evento] => Array (
                    [id] => 1
                    [nome] => Event 1
                )
            [Obreiro] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                            [id] => 2
                            [usuario_id] => 4
                            [nome] => Teste
                        )
                    [1] => Array (
                            [id] => 5
                            [usuario_id] => 8
                            [nome] => Teste
                         )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [Evento] => Array (
                    [id] => 2
                    [nome] => Event 2
                )

            [Obreiro] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                            [id] => 3
                            [usuario_id] => 6
                            [nome] => Teste
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [usuario_id] => 7
                            [nome] => Teste
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

And array `$obreiros`:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [Obreiro] => Array (
                    [id] => 2
                    [usuario_id] => 4
                    [nome] => Foo
                )
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [Obreiro] => Array (
                    [id] => 5
                    [usuario_id] => 8
                    [nome] => Bar
                )
        )
)
```

I want to do:
For each `$obreiros` which is a user, show if participated or not of the event (defined in array `$evento[x]['Obreiro'][y]`, where x and y are numbers).

Sample:

```
       | Event 1 | Event 2 | Event n
--------------------------------------
Foo    |    x    |         |    x    
Bar    |    x    |    x    |
Foo 2  |         |         |    x
```

How I can do this?

Comment: i'd suggest you rearrange your arrays. You have ID's. Use them as array-keys instead of [0]/[1] (unless they may occure multiple times at the same level). This doesn't answer your question but you may get there easier.

Comment: Thanks @user247245, I have not thought this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have done the work with the code:

```
foreach($obreiros as $kObreiro => $obreiro) {
    foreach($eventos as $kEvento => $evento) {
        $faltou = true;

        if(isset($evento['Obreiro']) && is_array($evento['Obreiro']) && count($evento['Obreiro']) > 0) {
            foreach($evento['Obreiro'] as $kEventoObreiro => $eventoObreiro) {
                if($eventoObreiro['usuario_id'] == $obreiro['Usuario']['id']) {
                    $faltou = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if($faltou) {
            echo'X';
        } else {
            echo' ';
        }
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```